# В будущем мы хотели бы сделать сотрудничество с вами. Правильно или нет?

Tags: грамматика

В будущем мы хотели бы сделать сотрудничество с вами.

Правильно?

Comment: Нет, не правильно.

Comment: at the very least организовать сотрудничество which is much more idiomatic

Comment: also наладить сотрудничество

Comment: Best say: Мы бы хотели сотрудничать (работать) с вами в дальнейшем

Answer (score 7):

Nobody ever says “сделать сотрудничество”. A more correct example would be:

> В будущем мы хотели бы сотрудничать с вами.